# cordova plugin install <dir> silently fails

Tags: cordova

When I try to install a plugin from source by using

cordova plugin install D:\projekt\open_source\Telerik-Verified-Plugins\Mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=heres_goes_an_access_token

I will only list already existing plugins so the output will be:
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"

Is it possible to install a plugin from a dir (containing plugin.xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'cordova plugin add'. There is no install command.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Wonder how I did not get an error message!

Comment: Adding and removing the plugin forth and back is the only way of testing changes in the source, right?

Comment: I don't think you should have to. When you run Cordova build, it checks your plugin's source and updates the one on your project. So, you should only have to do it the once.

Comment: Seems to not be the case, but I agree that would be something to wish for.

Comment: Shouldnt cordova plugin add dir change config.xml?

Comment: You have to use the '--save' flag for it to edit your config file.